# Make Windows use Internet sparingly

Tags: windows-8, internet

How can I make Windows use as little Internet as possible (browser only for instance).

I am relying on mobile Internet (Max 1GB traffic) and I don't want Windows to run background operations that will eat up my plan.

Comment: Windows 8 and above supports setting a wireless connection as a metered connection.  Does this satisfy your requirements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow network traffic only for specific programs in windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/403308/allow-network-traffic-only-for-specific-programs-in-windows-7), and/or [How do I stop Windows Operating System from using up my bandwidth quota?](http://superuser.com/questions/463020/how-do-i-stop-windows-operating-system-from-using-up-my-bandwidth-quota), also see [Restrict programs from accessing the Internet](http://superuser.com/questions/15425/restrict-programs-from-accessing-the-internet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in my comments, and as others have posted, Windows 8 will make it easy.

First off, download and install Firefox; it uses it's own proxy settings if you tell it to, without requiring Admin rights.

Once it's installed, set it to either auto-detect a Proxy, or to use No Proxy, depending on your setup (Options->Advanced->Network). You can also tell Windows 8 you are on a Metered connection in PC Settings->Network-> **choose the Wifi**->Set as Metered Connection.

Now, open the Administrative Command Prompt (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to bring up the menu), and type in `netsh winhttp set proxy 127.0.0.1`. This makes default programs and all Windows background services look for a proxy server at `127.0.0.1` (your `localhost`, aka the machine you're on) to get Internet Access. Firefox will ignore this setting, and allow you to work wherever you want.

To disable this, run `netsh winhttp reset proxy` from the Administrative Command Prompt; this will reset it to the original configuration.

Answer (score -1):

A off-the-wall way of doing this would be to set the proxy settings under Control Panel>Internet Options to a fake IP address (ex: 0.0.0.0) and then use a browser (or browser extension) to set your proxy to "None" for that application only. That way, all Windows traffic by default will timeout or fail unless you specify in an application to use no proxy.

Comment: Not all Windows processes honour that proxy setting

Comment: I'm not aware of any Windows-specific processes or programs that don't use the system proxy setting. I've only seen 3rd party programs that don't respect the system proxy setting. Do you have one in mind?

Comment: Automatic updates for Windows.use the netsh winhttp proxy function for that